# Is there a way to toggle between versions of R on linux?

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I have two versions of R on my linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04). I need R 4.0.2 to run an analysis that requires library (psych); and I need R 3.6.3 to run an afni analysis (3dLME). Right now, R 4.0.2 is in usr/bin/R and R 3.6.3 is usr/local/bin. However, "which R" will only return /usr/bin/R.

I have tried to add /usr/local/bin/R to my .bashrc with no luck. Is there a way to toggle back and forth between which R version that linux will use? Optimally, I would like Rstudio to use 4.0.2, but afni to use 3.6.3; but I am also fine with editing my .bashrc file when I need to use the different tools. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See if [this tutorial](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop) helps. It states, as part of the instructions,

> If you want to override which version of R is used then you can set
> the RSTUDIO_WHICH_R environment variable to the R executable that you
> want to run against. For example:
>
> export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/local/bin/R Not that in order for RStudio
> to see this environment variable when launched from the Ubuntu desktop
> Applications menu (as opposed to from a terminal) it must be defined
> in the ~/.profile file.

Comment: Thanks - yes, I saw this in previous posts. The problem is that I actually want to use the default version with R studio (the one in /usr/bin/R). I want another program (afni) to use the R version in /usr/local/bin/R, so it does not work to change through R studio (unless I uninstall and reinstall in the opposite locations).

Comment: @Dani Please explain what "afni" is, then.  I thought it was an `R` package you wanted to run.  If it's something that calls `R` then you need to specify the path inside "afni"